# Does Open source Kendo UI Core has Server Side Extensions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik

As we know Kendo UI Core is open source. But I want to confirm if it contains client side controls only or it also contains Server Side Extensions/Helper/Wrapper For ASP.NET MVC in open source package or not.

Thanks

Comment: You should ask this directly in Telerik forum.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something that Telerik Sales should answer free of charge.

Comment: Kendo UI Core is open source project powered by Telerik :D

Answer (score 1):

The Kendo UI Server Side Extensions/Helper/Wrapper For ASP.NET MVC are paid as shown at http://www.telerik.com/purchase/aspnet-mvc

Answer (score 0):

just to add information for other readers, Kendo UI Core is open source project and provides Front-end extensions only. Backend extensions are part of their professional/enterprise package.